# How to create a column of percentages within a grouped dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, percentage

I have created a frequency table, DF, using the code below. However I would also like to create a column of percentages/proportions within the table, to see the percentage/proportion of each Function for each key. I am not sure how to adapt my code to do this. Any advice and help would be appreciated!

````
  gather(key = 'key', value = 'freq', -Function) %>%
  mutate(freq = as.numeric(freq)) %>% 
  group_by(Function, key) %>% 
  summarise(freq=sum(freq)) ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = 'key', value = 'freq', -Function) %>%
  mutate(freq = as.numeric(freq)) %>% 
  group_by(key, Function) %>% 
  summarise(freq=sum(freq)) %>% #..... (1)
  mutate(freq = freq/sum(freq))
```

Note that -

- `gather` has been retired, so use `pivot_longer` instead.
- The above works without grouping by `key` explicitly because when you do `summarise` at (1) only last level of grouping is dropped i.e `Function`, so data is still grouped by `key` at (1).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can continue by grouping by key and the calculate the percentage/proportion

```
gather(key = 'key', value = 'freq', -Function) %>%
mutate(freq = as.numeric(freq)) %>% 
group_by(Function, key) %>% 
summarise(freq = sum(freq))  %>% 
group_by(key) %>%
mutate(prop = freq / sum(freq))
```